# Extending a generic type

Tags: oop, scala, type-systems

I am stuck with a "simple" problem. I am working with files metadata. I would like to provide both a read-only view (`trait ReadOnly`) with just getters as well as a read-write view (`trait ReadWrite`) with getters and setters. Each read-write view must extend a read-only view.

```
trait ReadOnly 

trait ReadWrite

trait BasicRO extends ReadOnly {
  def foo: String
  def bar: Int
}

class BasicRW extends ReadWrite with BasicRO {
  def foo: String = ???
  def foo_=( str: String ): Unit = ???
  def bar: Int = ???
  def bar_=( i: Int ): Unit = ???
}
```

So far so good. But now, I would like to add a `snapshot` method to `ReadWrite` which will return the corresponding `ReadOnly` view (the same that was extended by the `ReadWrite` sub-class). In *pseudo-scala*, I would like to define this constraint as:

```
trait ReadWrite[T <: ReadOnly] extends T {
  def snaphsot: T
}
```

But it does not compile because `class type required but T found` (compiler message). Is there a way to express this constraint in the Scala type-system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, you want snapshot to be in a separate trait, but it can only be used in a class which also extends ReadOnly?

You can use a self type for this

```
trait ReadOnly[T]

trait ReadWrite[T] { self: ReadOnly[T] => 
   def snapshot: T
}

trait BasicRO[T] extends ReadOnly[T] {
  def foo: String
  def bar: Int
}

abstract class class1[T] extends ReadOnly[T] with ReadWrite[T]  // legal

abstract class class2[T] extends ReadWrite[T] // Not legal

abstract class class3[T] extends BasicRO[T] with ReadWrite[T] // legal
```

This doesn't make `ReadWrite` extend `ReadOnly`, but it both requires that the base object also mix in a `ReadOnly` (with the same type parameter) and gives `ReadWrite` access to `ReadOnly`'s methods, while allowing the two traits to be subclassed entirely independently of eachother.

Comment: You are partially right regarding my answer (which I have now deleted) - I did check it in the REPL and it seemed to work fine there, but more extensive checking showed I had misinterpreted the output.

Comment: Ok, I will delete my reference to the deleted solution

Comment: Thanks. Adding the constraint `trait ReadOnly[T <: ReadOnly[T]]` to your solution, does the trick I am looking for.

Comment: @itsbruce Because the type `T` returned by `snapshot` must be a `ReadOnly` also. Another approach is to change the `snapshot` signature to return an `ReadOnly[T]` instead of `T`.

Comment: Oh, you're confusing two different things, here.  I was wondering why, in your question, ReadWrite was generic but the other classes and traits were not.  That's not how generics work.  You cannot mix ReadWrite[T] into a subclass of ReadOnly that way - that [T] does not refer to the class mixing in the trait.

Comment: @itsbruce I just want to ensure that each `ReadWrite` instance does extend any `ReadOnly` subtrait and provides a `snpashot` method returning another instance of the *same* `ReadOnly` subtrait. Since I want this constraint to be enforced at compile time, I am using here the generic system to describe the constraint. With the addition I proposed, your solution allows me to do exactly that. So I'm accepting your answer, despite our different point of view.